# max-device-width and orientation change

Tags: html, css

I have the code below:

```
@media all 
    and (max-device-width: 360px) {
        div {
            background-color: green;
            }
        }

@media all
    and (min-device-width: 361px)
    and (max-device-width: 640px) {
        div {
            background-color: blue;
            }
        }
```

But when i change the orientation of my android phone the colors doesn't change. Why does it happens while as i checked the `window.innerWidth` changes from 640px (landscape) to 360 (portrait)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set portrait and landscape media queries in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

Always set the *viewport* in the *head*.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more details about viewport **meta tag** [go here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/).

Here list some basic media query list

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Go to here for more details about [Media Query](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

I'm using a better one. I find out that these media queries break points match many more devices and desktop screen resolutions.

All media queries responsive menu + media break points

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){ ... }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1999px){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `max-device-width` twice. Sometimes we don't realize it, it happens.

The correct sintax is:

```
@media all
    and (min-device-width: 361px)
    and (max-device-width: 640px) {
        div {
            background-color: blue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, i've corrected it out. So Can You now answer my question?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gonecQYuAYp5YsLfzxPD?p=preview 

Your solution, probably you forgot the viewport meta.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the viewport in the head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You may want to try using max-width and min-width rather than max-device-width and min-device-width, depending on if you are testing in a browser vs. on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

This Media Query using only for devices not for browsers. check with devices

```css
/* SAMSUNG NOTE 2 in PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width:1920px) and (orientation : portrait) {
 div { 
  background-color: green;
 }
}

/* SAMSUNG NOTE 2 in LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width:1920px) and (orientation : landscape) {
 div { 
  background-color: blue;
 }
}

/*  IPAD in PORTTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: green;
 }
}

/*  IPAD in LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: blue;
 }
 }


/* IPHONE4 LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: green;
 } 
}

/* IPHONE5 PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: blue;
 }
}

/* SAMSUNG S4 in PORTRAIT */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: green;
 }
}

/* SAMSUNG S4 in LANDSCAPE */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width :640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
 div { 
  background-color: blue;
 }
}
```