# How to keep same style of `portrait` to `landscape` for iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad

Some reasons, I require to keep the same style as `portrait` to `landscape` too. How to achieve that using `css3` media query?

Because there is some of functionality disabled for touch pads.

I tried but it still shows the `desktop` view

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:1024px){}
```

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css)?

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css

Comment: ah @Swellar has just commented the same!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set portrait and landscape media queries in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check [this](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) too. Below are the ios related ones.

```css
   


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}


/**********
iPad 3
**********/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}



/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 6 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
```