# How to set up media queries for Ipads and Tablets for portrait and landscape orientations in CSS

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

When I use this code(see below) the media query does not work

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (orientation : portrait) { //scss code }
```

But when I remove the **'and (orientation : portrait)'** part it works. i.e

```
//this code works
@media (min-width: 768px) { //scss code }
```

How can I set up media queries for Ipads and Tablets for portrait and landscape orientations in CSS?

PS: I am coding a responsive layout for the web and I am using scss mixins (don't know if that affects anything.)

Comment: it is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set portrait and landscape media queries in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) { 
    /* STYLES HERE */
    }
```

Comment: It would be better to provide an explanation along with your code.