# Disable CSS transition when phone changes orientation (landscape/portrait)

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, orientation, transition

On my page I have a:

```
<div id="id_modal_background"></div>
```

that is between a modal login window and a background image. It's task is to *(a)* blur the background image once the modal login window is shown and *(b)* dismantle the blur when modal login window is closed.

In order for the blur to look nice it needs transition time of 1s, which is set in CSS like this:

```
#id_modal_background{
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

But this transition time gives me side effects on phones where change of the orientation from landscape to portrait *(but not vice versa)* needs `1s` to redraw the blur. And it doesn't looks nice.

[image]

I am using this function to draw (`id_modal_background_visibility(1)`) or dismantle (`id_modal_background_visibility(0)`) the blur:

```
function id_modal_background_visibility(a){

    let r = '';
    let m = document.getElementById('id_modal_background');

    switch(a){
        case 0:
            r = 'OFF';
            // In order to reference "backdrop-filter" we camelcase it!
            m.style.backdropFilter = 'blur(0px) grayscale(0)';
            m.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            break;
        case 1:
            r = 'ON';
            // In order to reference "backdrop-filter" we camelcase it!
            m.style.visibility = 'visible';
            m.style.backdropFilter = 'blur(15px) grayscale(0.25)';
            break;
        default:
            r = 'ERROR';
            m.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            break;
    }

    console.log('Modal background visibility: ' + r);
}
```

If anyone can help me to remove the transition time that happens at any kind of orientation change, but keep the transition time otherwise, I would be more than happy.

Comment: its way too big too read, please try shorting your question, will save all of us lot of time

Comment: I figured out one part of the problem. If I isolate transition only to `backdrop-filter` by using `transition: backdrop-filter 1s;` instead of `transition: 1s;` the problem is gone, but new problem arizes, because now transition works on opening the modal login window, but it doesn't work on closing the window...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of css `media queries`

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

Read more here [How to set portrait and landscape media queries in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861189/how-to-set-portrait-and-landscape-media-queries-in-css)

Comment: I know about them, but they reference the position, while my problem happens on a **change** of position, so I am curious if you can provide a complete solution to this using `@media` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your code like below :

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        console.log("Portrait");
    } else {
        console.log("Landscape");
    }
}, true);
```

And you can apply CSS class accordingly. Also media query CSS is a possible way for your problem.